# Format of the initialization string Error when connecting to Azure DB after deployment. Works fine locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-5, azure-sql-database

**SOVLED: Had a % in my password which works run from my local machine. Reset password and changed the % to a # and it works fine! **

I have an MVC 4 app using EF and Azure. I can connect and run the application pointing to the Azure DB just fine from my local machine but it doesn't run on deployment. I get the following error:
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index **130**.

Please note that my error states index 130 while all the other reported instances of this error state index 0.

I'm not sure what is going on. Anyone have ideas? I've been searching for a while now and I haven't come up with anything useful.

I'm using code first EF.

Web Config for connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="my_db" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=my_db;User ID=mydblogin@server;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Relevant stack trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 130.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5312764
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +66
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential) +26
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +6
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString) +216
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString) +282
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +301
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context) +101
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +352
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
   System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63
```

Comment: if you include the full stack trace of the exception, along with relevant code lines and web.config (including web.release.config and web.debug.config) there is better chance for help. Otherwise we are just starring at the crystal ball.

Comment: Solved the problem. It was a percent sign (%) in my password. Changed that to a # and updated the connection string and it now works.